# I am trying to compute the accuracy of L2 SVM using scikit learn

Tags: python

I am running the following code:

```
G = (matrix([[ 0.01615591,  0.0297292 ,  0.00954122, ...,0.02076448,0.01801039,  0.03154632]]), matrix([[ 0.01615591,  0.0297292 ,  0.00954122, ...,  0.02076448,0.01801039,  0.03154632]]))

filter_selector =  SelectKBest(G)
classifier = LinearSVC(penalty = 'l2', dual =False)
filter_svm = make_pipeline(filter_selector, classifier)
cv = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, 5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
print np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(filter_svm, X,y, cv=cv))
```

When I run this code I get the following error :

> IndexError: index 113 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Could you please let me know how  to resolve this I am trying to compute accuracy for features selected using selector K Best method

Comment: Give the traceback. Which function is throwing the error? What are the dimensions of your dataset? What are X and y?

Comment: X and y dimension is (200L, 10000L) (200L,)

Comment: and print np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(filter_svm, X,y, cv=cv)) this line is throwing the error ..traceback is :    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/python/Part3.py", line 132, in <module>
    print np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(filter_svm, X,y, cv= 5))
  packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1361, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv)

Comment: Hard to tell. The source code is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py), so you can see the function throwing the error, but it doesn't have that line in it (guessing you have an older version). You can try `verbose=True` in `cross_val_score` and see if it gives you more information. At some point, it's trying to access index 113 along an axis with size 1. It could be the extra axis with nothing in it in your y vector.